# About setting images which are large enough for any android devices

Tags: android

As far as I googled about it, in general, you provide several images with different scales and put each image into folders like ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and so on.
The question is if there are any problems with that I provide a image with only one scale which is large enough.
Using 'dip' it resizes the images smaller for several device resolutions.

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as long as it is a vector image you should be fine

Comment: thanks! Well then, I think everybody should provide images with just one scale.

Comment: that would be nice, part of the problem is their are some weird sizes that don't fit into a category as well as vector images are rather expensive to make.  One graphic designer told me it was a 3X time difference (and thus 3x price) for vector compared to raster images

Answer (score 1):

if you using bitmap image yes you should provide several image with different resolution but if you have no problem with bad quality image when it forced to be streched to big resolution no you didn't need to provide it.

for showing the image in the device I prefer measuring the device size (width and height)
then scale it programatically

I think this should be enough, but if you have some other question about this topic feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: The other option is getting a high quality large image and shrinking it down, you won't lose any quality that way, just takes up more space